# How to draw something (line, circle etc.) on a Gtk# Window?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, gtk#

I'm using Mono and C#. I would like to create a "graphical" application.

In WinForms and .NET I can use System.Drawing. What can I use with GTK#?

And, how is the performance of GTK# under Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done with Mono.Cairo, which is a wrapper around a native drawing library (like GDI+), so it performs pretty well.

Example (draw a line):

```
using (Cairo.Context g = CairoHelper.Create (myWindow.GdkWindow)) {
    g.MoveTo (0, 0);
    g.LineTo (10, 10);
    g.Color = new Color (1, 1, 1);
    g.Stroke ();
}
```

Cairo is missing higher level functions, like DrawRectangle and FillRectangle.  Pinta has a bunch of extension methods that add these functions you might want to look at:

https://github.com/jpobst/Pinta/blob/master/Pinta.Core/Extensions/CairoExtensions.cs